# exim: "remote host address is the local host"

Tags: email, dns, exim

I try to set up an exim mail server and I get the error

temporarily rejected RCPT : remote host address is the local host

domain.com points to the local host, the MX from domain.com point to the local host, but the fully qualified domain name of local host is otherdomain.com, which I suspect is related to the problem.

Both domain.com and otherdomain.com are set up in the exim configuration file:

```
domainlist local_domains = domain.com : otherdomain.com
```

The server does not fill up any mailboxes.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in *domainlist local_domains*, you have a "pointer" to the actual list:

```
domainlist local_domains = MAIN_LOCAL_DOMAINS
```

while the list of domains is in

```
dc_other_hostnames='example.com;example2.com'
```

a single-quotes enclosed, semicolon separated list. (You have a colon there.)

Also decide on one mail host, while this mail host may receive mail for multiple domains (which are all listed in *dc_other_hostnames*). Add an MX record to otherdomain.com, pointing to your mail host.

Make sure the mail host has the FQDN you set in exim. If the FQDN and what exim thinks it is don't align, you get above error.  If you need to [set your FQDN](http://linux.goeszen.com/exim4-temporarily-rejected-rcpt-problem-solved.html), edit `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` and commit these changes by calling `hostname -F /etc/hostname` ([via](http://linux.goeszen.com/exim4-temporarily-rejected-rcpt-problem-solved.html))